# iphone accelerometer speed and distance

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, distance

I want to find **distance traveled and velocity** from **accelerometer** events. Like iphone's gMeter application is doing.

Any suggestion, by which value or formula I should use for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the acceleration values from the accelerometer to measure the velocity and distance. There is really good paper ([Implementing Positioning Algorithms Using Accelerometers](http://www.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3397.pdf)) which explains the errors you get from the accelerometer and the techniques to get the velocity and position from the acceleration values.

Some pseudo code:

`velocity[i] = (acceleration[i] + acceleration[i-1])/2 * interval + velocity[i-1]`
`distance[i] = (velocity[i] + velocity[i-1])/2 * interval + distance[i-1]`

`interval` is the time between `acceleration/velocity[i]` and `acceleration/velocity[i-1]` which is related to the update frequency of the accelerometer.

To increase accuracy you have to filter the acceleration values in the forehand. I've implemented such an algorithm on an iPhone 3GS and it worked pretty good. The accelerometer let's you measure distances of 30 cm with an error of approximately 1 cm. I didn't tested longer distances yet.

Comment: If I understand this properly, you'd have to keep track of static acceleration from Earth's gravity since the device's physical orientation could change. Throwing it through the air would cause it to tumble, changing "down". I'm not sure if my interpretation of this is right, but I think the single "calibration" described in the paper assumes a constant orientation of the device.

Comment: That's right, this approach assumes that the device's orientation doesn't change during the movement.

Comment: @brutella could you please provide your algorithm?