# How to calculate correct velocity values from accerometer

Tags: iphone, ios, core-motion, acceleration

I need to calculate iphone velocity in space, punch speed for example.
My first question is: Are the acceleration values `accelerometer:didAccelerate`with this filtering actions:

```
gravity_x = acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor + gravity_x * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
gravity_y = acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor + gravity_y * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
gravity_z = acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor + gravity_z * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
float gravityNorm = sqrt(gravity_x * gravity_x + gravity_y * gravity_y + gravity_z * gravity_z);
accelX = acceleration.x - gravity_x / gravityNorm;
accelY = acceleration.y - gravity_y / gravityNorm;
accelZ = acceleration.z - gravity_z / gravityNorm;
```

the same as using CoreMotion's
`motionManager.deviceMotion.userAcceleration.x;
motionManager.deviceMotion.userAcceleration.y;
motionManager.deviceMotion.userAcceleration.z;` ?
Next, according to same questions, I do the following

```
    const float accuracy=10;
    float accx = (float) ((int)  (accelX * accuracy))/ accuracy;
    float accy=  (float) ((int)  (accelY * accuracy))/ accuracy;
    float accz=  (float) ((int)  (accelZ * accuracy))/ accuracy;
```

for rounding values, then, as I think, I obtain current speed

```
float dx = accx*9.81+prevX*9.81;
float dy = accy*9.81+prevY*9.81;
float dz = accz*9.81+prevZ*9.81;

speed_after_x = dx/2*myAccelerometer.updateInterval+speed_before_x;
speed_after_y = dy/2*myAccelerometer.updateInterval+speed_before_y;
speed_after_z = dz/2*myAccelerometer.updateInterval+speed_before_z;
```

according to [iphone accelerometer speed and distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177199/iphone-accelerometer-speed-and-distance)

then

```
    prevX=accx;
    prevY=accy;
    prevZ=accz;

    speed_before_x=speed_after_x;
    speed_before_y=speed_after_y;
    speed_before_z=speed_after_z;
```

and finally calculating speed as vector's length

```
    float speed = sqrt(speed_after_x*speed_after_x+speed_after_y*speed_after_y+speed_after_z*speed_after_z);
    if (max_speed<speed)  max_speed = speed;
```

But speed value, that is containing in label, is always increasing. I mean if i moved device and then stopped, speed value doesn't become to 0. Doesn't acceleration compensate itself at 0?

Comment: Doesn't this cancel itself out:  `((int)  (accelX * accuracy))/ accuracy;`.  Like ((10 * 100) / 100 == 10.  If your intention is to round the number and then cast back to a float there are better ways to do it.

Comment: accuracy is 10, to avoid rapidly acceleration values changing when device is holding.

Comment: Yes, but multiplying a number then dividing by the same number is the equivalent of doing nothing.  (A * B) / B = A.

Comment: I don't think that this is why velocity doesn't change into 0, anyway, I have to use `acceleration.timestamp`s delta, not exactly `updateInterval`

Comment: Oh I know, that's why it's a comment not an answer.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using Core Motion?  I think that is available in >=ios4.0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the example code I managed to hash out.  I'll just put it here for now:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Acce
//
//  Created by Diziet on 14/05/2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    UIAccelerationValue gravX;
    UIAccelerationValue gravY;
    UIAccelerationValue gravZ;
    UIAccelerationValue prevVelocity;
    UIAccelerationValue prevAcce;
}

@property (strong) UIAccelerometer *sharedAcc;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize sharedAcc = _sharedAcc;

#define kAccelerometerFrequency        50.0 //Hz
#define kFilteringFactor 0.1

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.sharedAcc = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    self.sharedAcc.delegate = self;
    self.sharedAcc.updateInterval = 1 / kAccelerometerFrequency; 

    gravX = gravY = gravZ = prevVelocity = prevAcce = 0.f;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (UIAccelerationValue)tendToZero:(UIAccelerationValue)value {
    if (value < 0) {
        return ceil(value);
    } else {
        return floor(value);
    }
}

#define kAccelerometerFrequency        50.0 //Hz
#define kFilteringFactor 0.1
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    gravX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (gravX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
    gravY = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (gravY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
    gravZ = (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (gravZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));

    UIAccelerationValue accelX = acceleration.x - ( (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (gravX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );

    UIAccelerationValue accelY = acceleration.y - ( (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (gravY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );
    UIAccelerationValue accelZ = acceleration.z - ( (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (gravZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );
    accelX *= 9.81f;
    accelY *= 9.81f;
    accelZ *= 9.81f;
    accelX = [self tendToZero:accelX];
    accelY = [self tendToZero:accelY];
    accelZ = [self tendToZero:accelZ];

    UIAccelerationValue vector = sqrt(pow(accelX,2)+pow(accelY,2)+pow(accelZ, 2));
    UIAccelerationValue acce = vector - prevVelocity;
    UIAccelerationValue velocity = (((acce - prevAcce)/2) * (1/kAccelerometerFrequency)) + prevVelocity;

    NSLog(@"X %g Y %g Z %g, Vector %g, Velocity %g",accelX,accelY,accelZ,vector,velocity);

    prevAcce = acce;
    prevVelocity = velocity;
}

@end
```

It'll need modifying for your needs, especially as I'm just throwing the values away afterwards.  The resultant value 'velocity' logged as 'Velocity' tends back towards extremely small negative values after acceleration events have ceased, e.g. *10^-17.  So yeah, that's practically zero in my book.  You'll want to do some rounding in there and probably even scale the values up.  I don't think I could get it higher than 0.2 or 0.3 but then again I don't want to hurl my phone across the room (yet).

Comment: I don't think so, because I added this multiplier after found out the problem, and it is used to convert G-measures to m per sec

Comment: It's not the * 9.81 I'm wondering about, that was an 'also'/aside.  It's the fact that you add accx to prevX.  If prevX cannot be negative, which judging by your math I don't think it can be, then you will get a constantly increasing value for acceleration.   You need to have some multiplication of the existing value, such that if the current moment acceleration in a particular axis is zero the acceleration you record will be zero.  I'll put this in the answer.

Comment: why prevX cannot be negative?`prevX=accx;
    prevY=accy;
    prevZ=accz;`accx can be negative. I add accx to prevX according to `velocity[i] = (acceleration[i] + acceleration[i-1])/2 * interval + velocity[i-1]`

Comment: update interval is 0.01, i and i tried 0.05. This filter is for ignoring rotations around its own axes. What values you need to know?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11228/discussion-between-diziet-and-aft3rmath)

Comment: thanks) x*x faster then pow(x,2) as i know, am i wrong? and I don't need to calculate acceleration vector as I understand it, I need `i` and `i-1` accel values to calculate velocity as `v[i] = (a[i]+a[i-1])/2*delta t + v[i-1]` what I actually did, the problem is why velocity doesn't change into 0 when I stop moving device

Comment: I think that's as close as I'm going to get to solving this for you without getting some mighty funny looks where I work. :D

Comment: Dude, you are awesome! Don't test yet, but your help is great! Report you soon)

Comment: And I don't understand `UIAccelerationValue acce = vector - prevVelocity;` Why do you subtract previous velocity value from acceleration vector value

Comment: Because the acceleration at that instance is the change in velocity (e.g. current velocity minus previous).  If we are currently going (pretending units are m/s which they are not) 9 m/s and were going 12 m/s our acceleration is -3 m/s.  This lets the equation tend towards zero when motion stopped.  Without that you get continuously increasing values.

Comment: hm, can we compare m/s(velocity) with m/s^2 (acceleration)? Is it correct?

Comment: max detected speed is 0.33 m/s, seems to be incorrect =\ it must be 5-8 m/s with punch, now i'll try to apply it to core motion

Comment: Because I have no idea what the original measurements are in.

Comment: I need to to calculate the punch speed. Plz tell the final method you have implemented ..

Comment: Just because I can't comment, I post here : I think the unit of acceleration is in m/s^2. > A G is a unit of gravitation force equal to that exerted by the earth’s gravitational field (9.81 m s−2). https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAccelerometerData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CMAcceleration But it's with the method whit CMMotionManager to get acceleration...

Comment: Aha, I didn't know for sure it was G that was returned.  Excellent.

Comment: Why velocity is not  0 when device stoped?