# In iOS get user current speed and altitude

Tags: ios, xcode

In my app I am tracking user movement in map view.Basically it is a walking app. Now I have to calculate user current walking speed and altitude. How should I calculate the user current speed and altitude?

Answer (score 4):

CLLocation contains speed and altitude properties. Just use it. More details:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW26

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.manager.delegate = self;
        [self.manager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"Speed = %f", newLocation.speed);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to calculate the speed with accelerometer?

Comment: I never tried it but check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579004/how-to-calculate-correct-velocity-values-from-accerometer

Comment: thanks. I have no idea about accelerometer. Can u please tell me when should we use accelerometer? Please don't mind for asking the question.