# Find the walking distance using Accelerometer

Tags: iphone

Need to make an app in which user can find the walking distance between two points.

The Concept is like user will start the app and start walking and after taking a few steps he will click some button which will show him the distance traveled by him from the point where he just started the App. and to where he stopped.

I know we can find the distance between two location by using CLLocation Class but the challenge is to get the accurate measurements up to say 3 meters.

Even I am not sure that we can use accelerometer as If I'm at rest, the accelerometer detects only acceleration due to gravity. This obviously set the walking distance to 0 so dont know how will I detect the starting point.

Any hint/suggestion on the same would be a great help to me.

Comment: The accelerometer detects any acceleration. For example, if you're in a car that accelerates, your phone will detect a horizontal acceleration in addition to the background gravitational one.

Comment: I'm mainly concerned with implementing such functionality where iPhone is able to measure short distance moved from one point to another, using accelerometer is not must

Answer (score 1):

Check this: [iphone accelerometer speed and distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177199/iphone-accelerometer-speed-and-distance/)

As far as I know it is almost impossible to get accurate results about distance, using the accelerometer.