# How to convert accelerometer data into meter/second^2?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, accelerometer, uiaccelerometer

I  want to Convert accelerometer reading in x,y,z axis into acceleration in meter/second^2.I am developing a windows phone application to calculate the distance traveled by a taxi.I have already gone through some of links like

1. [My Algorithm to Calculate Position of Smartphone - GPS and Sensors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727298/my-algorithm-to-calculate-position-of-smartphone-gps-and-sensors)
2. [Calculating distance using Linear acceleration android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926459/calculating-distance-using-linear-acceleration-android)
3. http://blog.contus.com/how-to-measure-acceleration-in-smartphones-using-accelerometer/
4. [Distance moved by Accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645126/distance-moved-by-accelerometer)
5. [iphone accelerometer speed and distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177199/iphone-accelerometer-speed-and-distance)

   But I didn't get any idea about exact way to convert acclerometer reading to acceleration.I know this reading is not accurate,But for me this is fine for now because I am considering only long distances.Please see the below mentioned code to find what I am trying to  achieve

   ```
   private void CalculateAcceleration(AccelerometerReading accelerometerReading)
   {
        Vector3 acceleration = accelerometerReading.Acceleration;
        double xValue=acceleration.X;
        double yValue=acceleration.Y;
        double zValue=acceleration.Z;
        double accelerationInMeterPerSecondSquare="do something";
   }
   ```

   or some can please suggest some methods to calculate distances travelled from accelerometer readings

   I know I am poor in english.So I apologize for that.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally, accelerometers readings in g are convertible 1 g = 9.81 m s-2.  But listen to the advice in the answer to #4 above.  You cannot make this work, especially for long distances the math will produce a value dominated by error.  The problem is with the DC component of velocity that accumulates over time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Actualy I know it's covertable and I read it many place.But i am not clear how to do that.I am asking whether someone help me to complete this statement(double accelerationInMeterPerSecondSquare="do something";) in my code snippet

Comment: Multiply. xAccel = xValue * 9.81, yAccel = yValue * 9.81, etc

Comment: Thanks #jdr5ca,I will try this and I am planning to implement a better solution using gps.Thanks for the help